# libopenjp2-7-dev : No package found even after installing package in docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have been trying to run some commands at the docker entrypoint

`docker run -v $(pwd):/oin -w /oin --entrypoint /bin/sh ubuntu -c "apt-cache show kernel glibc systemd bash coreutils grub2-pc libmodulemd | tee manifest-ubu:Core.txt; apt-cache search glibc kernel | tee manifest-ubu:Old.txt; apt-cache show libopenjp2-7-dev | tee manifest-ubu:Graphics.txt" eric/ubuntu_image:latest_image`

However, I get an error message as `E: No packages found.` **( Error message related to the package libopenjp2-7-dev)**

Here are all the things I have done till now:

1. Cloned ubuntu’s image and named it eric/ubuntu_image and its
   corresponding container as ubuntu_image_container.

   Mounted volume onto this container, but everything works absolutely
   fine except for one package - libopenjp2-7-dev.libopenjp2-7-dev is
   an equivalent for openjpeg2 in ubuntu, as far as I could learn.
2. Even after installing libopenjp2-7-dev in the cloned image ( as base
   images are immutable) and after running the above command, I receive
   the following error: Package not found.
3. Was also able to find the installed package inside the cloned
   image’s container. The package location using the find command was
   found to be `./usr/share/doc/libopenjp2-7-dev`
4. Everything works fine when I remove the line which has libopenjp2-7-
   dev.

Some help will be deeply appreciated. I just don't understand why it is not able to find the package libopenjp2-7-dev